# A question about the tenses

Tags: tense, aspect

Consider:

> I had hoped to visit the gallery before I left Florence, but it's closed on Monday.

Q1 : Shouldn't it be it **was** closed ?

Q2 : Does present simple Imply more definite sense ? I mean "it is closed" imply that It has been closed on Monday from the Ice-age to the current moment !

Q3: Is it grammatical to use tenses in above sequence,   Past Perfect, Past Simple and **Present** ?

It must be noted the highlighted sentece belong to cambridge grammar book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine.

The present tense here is a 'generic':  it's always closed on Monday, *within the timeframe we're concerned with*. (This would be reinforced if *Monday* were *Mondays*, but that's not necessary.) The 'present' is a very loose notion, defined pragmatically by the context: if you're talking about my trips you're pretty much excluding most of recorded history as irrelevant to the conversation.

Comment: I am surprised.  The *apostrophe-s* is as much a contraction for **was** as it is for **is**.  What makes you or Cardinal think that "*it's*" means "*it **is***"?

Comment: @VictorBazarov Eh? *It's* can represent *it **has***, but I don't remember ever encountering it as *it **was***. ... and even if it did, that wouldn't work in OP's context.

Comment: Huh... I must have remembered wrong...  Or I was taught in the wrong school. Sorry, mates!

Comment: @StoneyB yes, it is "Mondays" in the book.

Comment: Besides *is* and *has*, it occasionally represents *does*: "What's this mean?"